# Regex forward slash

Tags: regex

What does a '/' character mean in a regular expression?

I have observed the following example to match single or double digit numbers.

```
/^\d{1,2}$/
```

When I googled multiple regex cheat sheets, the forward slash did not show up as a character with meaning in regex....

What does '/' do in regex?

Comment: Please tag the language that you are using.

Comment: It does not matter what language. These are regex delimiters. They are not part of the regex patterns, just separate regex action, pattern and modifiers.

Comment: `/` is to regex as `"` is to strings. It's just the delimiter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression meaning of a forward slash /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439417/regular-expression-meaning-of-a-forward-slash)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually *do* anything. In Javascript, Perl and some other languages, it is used as a delimiter character explicitly for regular expressions.

Some languages like PHP use it as a delimiter *inside* a string, with additional options passed at the end, just like Javascript and Perl (in this case, "m" for multi-line):

```
 preg_match("/^\d{1,2}$/m", $input);
```

With this syntax, you can also use other characters, which can make matching literal `/`'s easier:

```
 preg_match("![a-z]+/[a-z]+!i", "Example/Match");
```